# I have a file which is larger than memory size, how to handle such file?

Tags: c#, java

I am asking how to handle the file whose size is larger than memory size?

Comment: It depends. What do you need to do with it? If you're not doing anything with it then you don't need to worry.

Comment: Probably, wouldn't be different than any other large file. Because you have virtual memory. Your computer will do some recruiting form the disk space. It will be slow but it will work.

Comment: @T.S. FALSE. At 32 bits you can't load in memory a Blu Ray image (25-50gb). You can't even allocate enough address space for it (and even a  DVD DL is 8.4gb, more than the allocable address space of 32 bits)

Comment: @xanatos - may be this is because virtual memory also has a limit, which can be adjusted.

Comment: @T.S. No. Address space is a fixed quantity. 4gb on 32 bits, a big piece of which is used by the OS.

Comment: @xanatos - you're right. For the 32 bit this project is doomed. But 64 bit will probably work... up to limits of x64

Comment: @T.S. On 64 bits you still have only 8TB of address space/process... It can seem infinite, but it isn't. It's only 8x bigger than my "small" HD. Probably there are few files in the world that are bigger, but for example NTFS has a maximum file size of around 16 TB.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];

using (var fs = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    int num;

    while ((num = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        // now you have num bytes of your file in buffer, max 16384
    }
}
```

It will read the file in blocks of 16384 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to process it in a way that doesn't involve holding the entire file in memory.  Whether you can do this ... and how you would do it ... depends on the application.